# How to detect a UIScrollView has finished scrolling when animation is false?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView called timeline that is scrolling programmatically  on the second to last line here:

```
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if !onceOnly {
            let indexToScrollTo = IndexPath(row: self.posts.count - 1, section: 0)
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexToScrollTo, at: .left, animated: false)
            let firstPost = posts.first?.timeStamp
            let firstOfFirstMonth = firstPost?.startOfMonth()
            let diff = posts.last?.timeStamp.months(from: firstOfFirstMonth!)
            //self.currentPostMonth = diff
            let monthCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: diff!, section: 0)
            timeline.scrollToItem(at: monthCellIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
            onceOnly = true
        }
    }
```

later.. I am attempting to detect that this has finished scrolling with

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == timeline {
        print("Did finish")
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == timeline {
        print("Did finish")
    }
}
```

Neither print statement fires once the scroll has completed. I think partially because animation = false. When I set that to true, it prints Did finish correctly - I think specifically scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation prints even though scrollViewDidEndDecelerating still does nothing because its being scrolled programatically.

How can I detect that this scroll has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because you compare the collectionView with the scrollView

```
if scrollView == timeline
```

which is `false` , BTW you can use

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

If there is no animation then in the next line after

```
timeline.scrollToItem(at: monthCellIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
```

run what you want as it's will occur serially where scrolling ended successfully , no need to set it inside scrollView's delegate methods whether it's called or not

Comment: I didn't have issues with if scrollView == timeline. timeline is a collectionView but I think that means its also a scrollView right? In any case this was equating to true. scrollViewDidScroll was perfect. You might be right about just putting it after the scrollToItem if theres no animation. I am having trouble accessing cells after the scrollToItem but the scroll part did work so thanks!

Comment: FYI, if you want to check that scrollView and timeline are the same object, you have to use identity operators (===). From Swift documentation:
"Note that identical to (represented by three equals signs, or ===) doesn’t mean the same thing as equal to (represented by two equals signs, or ==). Identical to means that two constants or variables of class type refer to exactly the same class instance. Equal to means that two instances are considered equal or equivalent in value, for some appropriate meaning of equal, as defined by the type’s designer."